Is it Parashat or Parshat in construct form?
In construct form, is it parashat ______ or parshat _________ in naming Torah portions? How did authoritative grammar mavens bring it down?

See Esther 10:2

The singular is פָרָשָׁה (parashah). To form the construct, replace the ה with a ת, resulting in פָרָשַׁת (parashat).
